# Managing multiple forms in C++ builder XE3

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe3

I am using C++ Builder XE3 for my Test application. Project group contains a DLL ( with forms) and EXE ( containing main form and other forms). When i call DLL form using Form->Show() function, DLL form doesnot come at Top and stays behind Main Form and other forms of EXE. Even BringToFront() method doesnot work.
Is there any way by which DLL form behave similar to forms of EXE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your DLL is most likely compiled to be a standalone executable, and as such does not share the same RTL instance as the main EXE, so it has no concept of the EXE's `TApplication` and `MainForm` windows.  You should implement your Forms in a BPL package instead of a DLL, or at least enable Runtime Packages in both EXE and DLL projects.  Then they will share a common RTL instance.

Comment: RunTime package is enabled in both DLL and EXE project. Still not working. Converting DLL project to BPL may not be feasible. Any other option?